# differentiate with respect to a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives

consider the linear regression system $Y = BX +\epsilon$,
$\epsilon$ is normally distributed.
Prove that the least square estimator of B is $\hat{B}=(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY$.

Now we are looking for $\hat{B}=\min_B||BX-Y||^2 = \min_B (BX-Y)^T(BX-Y)$

Let $L = (\hat{B}X-Y)^T(\hat{B}X-Y) = X^T\hat{B}^T\hat{B}X+Y^TY-2(\hat{B}X)^TY$.

Now I have the problem of understanding the differentiation $\frac{\delta L}{\delta \hat{B}}$. L is a scalar, but how do we know that $\frac{\delta 2(\hat{B}X)^T Y}{\delta \hat{B}} = 2X^TY$?

Also in general: what does differentiating the following wrt B mean?

$B^T\overrightarrow{X},\overrightarrow{X}B, BA,\overrightarrow{X}^TB\overrightarrow{X}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For matrix-valued functions, you shall use the definition of the differential: for all matrix $H$ of the same size as $B$, we have (I will denote $\hat{B}$ simply by $B$):
\begin{align}
L(B+H)&=((B+H)X-Y)^T((B+H)X-Y)\\
%
&=\underbrace{(BX-Y)^T(BX-Y)}_{=L(B)}+(HX)^T(BX-Y)+(BX-Y)^THX\\
&\quad+\underbrace{(HX)^THX}_{=\mathcal{O}(\|H\|^2)}
\end{align}
Here we use the linearity of the transpose $A\mapsto A^T$. Hence the differential of $L$ is thus the linear map:
\begin{align}
\mathrm{d}L(B):H\mapsto (HX)^T(BX-Y)+(BX-Y)^THX.
\end{align}
Now you can try to optimize the function (in the $B$ direction) by cancelling the differential i.e. by finding $B$ such that $\mathrm{d}L(B)[H]=0$ for all matrix $H$ (if it is possible).

Note that the directional derivative $\frac{\partial L}{\partial H}(B)$ of $L$ at the point $B$ in the direction $H$ is by definition:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial H}(B):=\mathrm{d}L(B)[H].
\end{align}

Addendum: If $X$ is invertible, then $B:=YX^{-1}$ (provided that the sizes of the matrices match) is a solution.

Comment: I don't follow how dL(B) a function free of H takes any value from H and transform to $(HX)^T(BX-Y) + (BX-Y)^THX$

Comment: @smaillis The function $\mathrm{d}L(B)$ transforms any matrix $H$ (with the appropriate size) to the new matrix $(HX)^T(BX-Y)+(BX-Y)^THX$.